# How to get all hyperlinks from a large Google Sheets sheet efficiently?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Pretty basic question. Let's say I have a [sheet with 250,000 cells](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J20aivGnvLlAuyRIMMclIFUmrkHXUzgcDmYa31gdtCI/edit#gid=1663140350). I want to get a 2D array matching its dimensions with every hyperlink, or a nullish value if there is none, and have it reliably scale and not time out.

We may assume all cells are formatted as plain text (so `cell.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()` [works](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/268068963)). The solution should work in Google Apps Script.

I was wondering if there was a particular, maybe external, API call I could use, or a convenient-enough trick. EDIT: To clarify the question, **the goal is to make the link-fetching an order of magnitude faster**. And as per the comments, the time the code takes to run is very high variance, and maybe best observed by setting it to a timer trigger and later looking at the execution history.

```
let values = range.getDisplayValues()                          // 20s
let rtvs = range.getRichTextValues()                           // 20s
let links = rtvs.map(row => row.map(rtv => rtv.getLinkUrl()))  // 4min
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but I don't understand your question. You have mentioned "efficiency" and it appears that you are suggesting that `map` will take 4 minutes to extract the linkedURL; I tested your data using a simple nested loop and extracted the linked url in 90 seconds. Would you please clarify your question and explain what you mean by "efficiently".

Comment: Can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue using your provided Spreadsheet?

Comment: Sure thing, I shall make a demonstration later. But yes, it is just that one line in the real code, between two `console.log` bookends, so I can measure it. In practice, it often takes 4 minutes when called manually, and often times out when set to a timer trigger (these always run more slowly – try it out). Above all, the duration is extremely high variance.

My question was about looking for different solutions that can cut this by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Alright, here is a [demonstration](https://script.google.com/d/1ijMDOwuh8ksMtz2sjNEUeWHojAMcDRuIEepj4JMwnWhGsGVsa-C8RktM/edit?usp=sharing) based on my example sheet, and I will comment on it in a bit since I have found a solution (which is included in the demo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be to use **UrlFetchApp** instead of **SpreadsheetApp** within the Google Apps Script files. The latter is the native spreadsheet manipulation interface, whereas the former is a generic HTTP request client, which we set up to poll from Google Sheets API. There is a third option, **SheetsAPI** "advanced service", which seems also slow and unreliable.

The **UrlFetchApp** method requires an API key for Google Sheets API (go to [Google API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/), create a project, enable Sheets API, then create an API key (which you might restrict to Sheets API). These keys allow for read-only access, so can't be used to write to a sheet. But I think avoiding OAuth may be a secret to the speed of this method.

Here's a [demonstration](https://script.google.com/d/1ijMDOwuh8ksMtz2sjNEUeWHojAMcDRuIEepj4JMwnWhGsGVsa-C8RktM/edit?usp=sharing) of the two methods side-by-side, with a throwaway API key I made, that you can run.

Demo code:

```js
// sheet address
var ID = "1J20aivGnvLlAuyRIMMclIFUmrkHXUzgcDmYa31gdtCI"
var TAB = "Ultimate Star Spreadsheet v2"
// demonstration cell index
var [r,c] = [17,156]

function spreadsheetapp() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName(TAB)
  let range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())
  let values = range.getDisplayValues()
  console.log(`loaded values: ${values.length} × ${values[0].length}`)
  let rtvs = range.getRichTextValues()
  console.log(`loaded rtvs: ${rtvs.length} × ${rtvs[0].length}`)
  let links = rtvs.map(row => row.map(rtv => rtv.getLinkUrl()))
  console.log(`loaded links: ${links.length} × ${links[0].length}`)
  let table = values.map((_, i) => values[0].map((_, j) => ({value: values[i][j], link: links[i][j]})))
  console.log(`converted to [][]{value, link} format; cell at [${r}][${c}]: ${JSON.stringify(table[r][c])}`)
}

function urlfetchapp() {
  let apiKey    = "AIzaSyANhlntzk5lbrtqX86942JzE3StpWdAgc0"
  let fieldMask = "sheets.data.rowData.values(formattedValue,hyperlink)"   // selects data
  let response  = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${ID}?ranges=${TAB}&fields=${fieldMask}&key=${apiKey}`
  )
  console.log(`fetched`)
  let table = JSON.parse(response).sheets[0].data[0].rowData.map(row => row.values?.map(
    cell => ({value: cell.formattedValue, link: cell.hyperlink})
  ) ?? [])        // row.values is undefined for empty rows
  // fill out table rows since otherwise they may not span table
  let width = Math.max(...(table.map(row => row.length)))
  table.forEach(row => row.push(...Array(width - row.length).fill({})))
  console.log(`converted to [][]{value, link} format; cell at [${r}][${c}]: ${JSON.stringify(table[r][c])}`)
}
```

Demo output:

```
spreadsheetapp()
6:54:12 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:54:16 AM  Info    loaded values: 703 × 354
6:54:35 AM  Info    loaded rtvs: 703 × 354
6:56:08 AM  Info    loaded links: 703 × 354
6:56:08 AM  Info    converted to [][]{value, link} format; cell at [17][156]: {"value":"20.73","link":"https://youtu.be/IFAEJ5HC5I4"}
6:56:08 AM  Notice  Execution completed

urlfetchapp()
6:51:00 AM  Notice  Execution started
6:51:02 AM  Info    fetched
6:51:03 AM  Info    converted to [][]{value, link} format; cell at [17][156]: {"value":"20.73","link":"https://youtu.be/IFAEJ5HC5I4"}
6:51:02 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

So, the SpreadsheetApp method ran in **1m56s**, and the UrlFetchApp method in **3s**... In this example, that's **40× faster** (what a joke).

I imagine this is a fairly common obstacle to optimising Google Apps Scripts so I hope this finds many future readers well!

**Advantages of UrlFetchApp**:

- Much faster,
- Parallelises fetches of different sheets via UrlFetchApp.fetchAll,
- Does not require cells to be formatted as plain text to detect links.

**Disadvantage of UrlFetchApp**:

- Have to create an API key.